# ValueError: The given username must be set. Error Occured Using Django for registering User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, user-registration

**raise ValueError('The given username must be set')** using django python
...
I have been trying to register a user using `from django.contrib.auth.models import user`

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.

def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')

        if password1 == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user=User.objects.create_user(username = username,password =password1, email = email)
                user.save()
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

register.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password2">AGAIN Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check">
<label class="form-check-label" for="check">Check me out</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

`user=User.objects.create_superuser(username = username,password =password1, email = email)`
I want to know that why it is just sending that The given username is must be set but instead I have set super_user already. How to resolve this? It is not getting the username by POST method or is there any other mistake which I am ignoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add **name** attribute in your input tags, something like this:

```
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
...
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" name="password1">
...
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2">
...
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
...
```

Comment: Yes It is right.. I just simply forget to add name attributes in my register.html file and maybe that's why views.py is not able to fetch any data

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is the use of `request.POST`. If this is a form, you probably want to change this to be `request.form` wherever you're using `request.POST`. At the moment, your line `request.POST.get("username")` is returning `None`, so when you try to save the user it complains.

Answer (score 0):

The Authentication system might be a little bit tricky if this is your first time doing it. I am going to link you with this project that i did a while ago; it has an authentication system with Django; it can help you out  :
https://github.com/Nouamanezh909/BLog_repo.

--Go to Accounts, there you  will find (
forms , view , everything you need.
)